# Where is Jaime Lannister heading to?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In "The Dragon and the Wolf" (*Game of Thrones*, S07E07), we see Jaime riding his horse and heading somewhere.

Where is he heading to, and why he did he cover his right hand? If it is because it is cold, his hand is made of gold, so why would he cover it?

Comment: I think he go in the North to help in the war against WW. And for the hand, I don't think that there is a need to cover his fake hand, other than a metaphorical way to cover his past

Comment: Important to not that he ditched his Lannister armor.

Comment: From being a complex character to a whitewashed one

Comment: "If it is because it is cold, his hand is made of gold, so why would he cover it?" Being made of gold would actually be a reason to cover it, if he did it because it was cold. [On having metal in your body in cold weather](https://b-reddy.org/2014/12/08/on-having-metal-in-your-body-surgical-implants-weather-pains-and-more/#ColdMetal). The hand would lose heat faster than Jaime's arm, and the hand would then start taking heat from his arm, making that arm feel colder than his other arm. **Note that I do not think Jaime actually covered it for temperature related reasons.**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## North

Jaime intends on keeping his oath to go north to help defeat the army of the dead. This is made clear with his conversation with Cersei before he leaves:

> J: You pledged our forces to fight our common enemy.
> C: I'll say whatever I need to say to ensure the survival of our house.
>   You expect me to trust the man who murdered our father? You expect me to command our troops to fight beside foreign scum, to fight for the Dragon Queen?
> J: You saw it with your own eyes.
>   You saw a dead man trying to kill us.
>   
> C: I saw it burn.
>   If dragons can't stop them, if Dothraki and Unsullied and Northmen can't stop them, how will our armies make a difference?
> J: This isn't about noble houses, this is about the living and the dead!
> C: And I intend to stay amongst the living.
>   Let the Stark boy and his new queen defend the North.
>   We stay here where we've always been.
>   
> J: **I made a promise.**

As for why he covers his hand, well he's trying to stay incognito. He's also lost his fancy armour and I also can't see his sword easily either. He doesn't want to be recognised and a big gold hand is a giveaway. See the scene here:

As @GhotiandChips says in the comments when he covers his hand it is also symbolic of him leaving Cersei. As we know she spent ages creating the hand and getting it just right even though it didn't seem useful to Jaime. See that scene here:

Comment: Covering his hand is also symbolic of ditching Cersei - if you recall, she commissioned the goldsmith and "spent days getting the details just right".

Comment: @GhotiandChips Good point I'll add that in.

Comment: Actually, as explained in the very video you posted, "days" was only "the better part of an afternoon". Hardly "ages".

Comment: @terdon Why would you take anything Cersei says at face value? TBH I understood that phrase to be a jest on her part, outlining how she's perfectly capable of being emotionally separate from Jaime, not as fact. If that was indeed the case, then how long she *actually* took to get it ready is of no issue.

Comment: @Ordous this answer uses what Cersei says to support the claim that she spent "ages creating the hand and getting it just right" so I was pointing out that she actually said she didn't.

Comment: @terdon And I'm pointing out that the circumstances and the way she says it leads me to believe that she was more truthful in the first instance, rather than the second. Making the "ages" part relevant and on point.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that Jaime's long been haunted by the notion that he is an oathbreaker for stabbing the mad king, his sacred charge, in the back, and murdering him. In the books, when he is in danger of dying, he hallucinates his former kingsguard members under the Mad King (except Ser Barristan) all appearing and telling him he is a coward and an oathbreaker. The long arc of Jaime's redemption has led to this moment, where he has found a worthwhile cause and oath, and is determined to keep it this time.

Comment: @TylerH I haven't read all the books so couldn't say for sure but it is hinted at in the show he's on the same arc. It's just less obvious.